# How to re-drop marker on the google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've got two functions:

```
function showMarkers() {
    hotspotsIterator = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        var obj = table[i];
        if(obj && obj.marker) {
            var obj = table[i];
            obj.marker.setMap(map);
        }
    }
}

function hideMarkers() {
    for(var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        var obj = table[i];
        if(obj && obj.marker) {
            obj.marker.setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

First is showing markers, and second is hiding them. When I first use showMarkers() there is Animation.DROP performed. But when I hide them and show again, animation is not running, and the markers are simply shown.

Can someone tell me how to re-drop markers? Without creating new instances?

**EDIT:**

I have already created the code to re-create the same marker and it works, but its not elegant solution at all!

And Google Docs for markers doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code right below the `obj.marker.setMap(map);` : `obj.marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);`

Here the reference: [Marker Animations](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#MarkerAnimations)

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted - it works like a charm. The only change I made was run setAnimation right after obj.marker.setMap(null); Thanks!